# Read File and store element as array Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, file

I am new to Scala and this is the first time I'm using it. I want to read in a textfile with with two columns of numbers and store each column items in a separate list or array that will have to be cast as integer. For example the textfile looks like this:

```
1 2 
2 3 
3 4 
4 5 
1 6 
6 7 
7 8 
8 9 
6 10
```

I want to separate the two columns so that each column is stored in its on list or array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you named the file as "columns", this would be a solution:

```
    val lines = Source.fromFile("columns").getLines() 
    /* gets an Iterator[String] which interfaces a collection of all the lines in the file*/
    val linesAsArraysOfInts = lines.map(line => line.split(" ").map(_.toInt)) 
    /* Here you transform (map) any line to arrays of Int, so you will get as a result an Interator[Array[Int]] */ 
    val pair: (List[Int], List[Int]) = linesAsArraysOfInts.foldLeft((List[Int](), List[Int]()))((acc, cur) => (cur(0) :: acc._1, cur(1) :: acc._2))
    /* The foldLeft method on iterators, allows you to propagate an operation from left to right on the Iterator starting from an initial value and changing this value over the propagation process. In this case you start with two empty Lists stored as Tuple an on each step you prepend the first element of the array to the first List, and the second element to the second List. At the end you will have to Lists with the columns in reverse order*/

    val leftList: List[Int] = pair._1.reverse
    val rightList: List[Int] = pair._2.reverse
    //finally you apply reverse to the lists and it's done :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way of doing this:

```
val file: String = ??? // path to .txt in String format
val source = Source.fromFile(file)

scala> val columnsTogether = source.getLines.map { line =>
  val nums = line.split(" ") // creating an array of just the 'numbers'
  (nums.head, nums.last) // assumes every line has TWO numbers only
}.toList
columnsTogether: List[(String, String)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (1,6), (6,7), (7,8), (8,9), (6,10))

scala> columnsTogether.map(_._1.toInt)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 6)

scala> columnsTogether.map(_._2.toInt)
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```